# Injecting CXF JAXRS MessageContext in an "in Interceptor"

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, cxfrs

I am trying to inject MessageContext in an Interceptor with the Phase as READ as follows

```
@Context
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext.MessageContext messageContext;
```

But this is not getting initialized and remains null.  Is it possible to inject org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext.MessageContext in Interceptor?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might need to add `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` into the cxf configuration file:

```
<jaxrs:server id="example" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <bean class="org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.CustomerService">
              <aop:scoped-proxy />
         </bean>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Also you have to create a setter method for your messageContext (this should be in your service class - here it is "org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.CustomerService"):

```
private MessageContext messageContext;

@Context
public void setMessageContext(MessageContext messageContext) {
    this.messageContext = messageContext;
}
```

Consider also this documentation link:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-FromSpring

Comment: I did not need to add the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>´ property. Only the MessageContext setter.